# Making log file of fails in batch after a MOVE operation

Tags: batch-file, logging, move

This is my initial batch script.

```
@echo off

if "%MACHINE%" == "0" ( call:verif TestFolder txt )
if "%MACHINE%" == "0" ( call:verif TestFolder exe )

goto:eof

:verif
if not exist %~1 ( mkdir %~1 )
move *.%~2 ..\..\%~1\
```

What I want to do, is log the file names that failed to move in log.txt

What I tried: robocopy ( supports logs but I'm not pleased because I want to log only the fails )

What I'm thinking would work is output stderr, something like:

```
move *.%~2 ..\..\%~1\ 2>stderr.txt
```

Outputs ( for a file with no rights )

```
Access is denied.
```

But how will I know for which .exe or .txt the error is? Needs to concatenate somehow with the file name.

Please let me know if you know a solution or a better way.

Comment: What about logging everything and filtering your log after you finish?

Comment: Does `move` set [ERRORLEVEL](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php) appropriately when it fails? If it does, you can conditionally append the file name after you detect the failure. `ECHO *.%~2 >> stderr.txt` It will append all the matched files, though.

Comment: If this is not what you want, I think you must use a more sophisticated tool. Move cannot be forced to tell you, which of the files caused it to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of moving all *`.txt` and `.exe` files at the same time - why not use a for loop to move them individually?

```
for %%a in (*.%~2) do move %%a ..\..\%~1\ || echo %%a>>fail.log
```

The code after `||` will only run if an error level is set by the move command.

Comment: +1 `Move` sets an errorlevel on `access denied` and `if the target file is in use`, in XP and Windows 8.1 so it's safe to assume it does.  Some double quotes might be helpful for spaces etc